# Dropdown list inside listview insert item template passing null to database

Tags: asp.net

Currently I have a dropdownlist with it's own sqldatasource that's populating the dropdownlist.
The ddl is inside a listviews, which also has it's on sqldatasource, insert item template.
However when we click insert the value passed to the dbase is a null.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                                Text="Insert" />
                            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                Text="Clear" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="td_t_idTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("td_t_id") %>' Enabled="false" />
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2iit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource30" 
                            DataTextField="document_name" DataValueField="document_id" 
                            SelectedIndex='<%# Bind("td_docid") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
```

I have tried to use both document_id and td_docid in my sqldatasource insertparameters.

```
<InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="td_t_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="td_docid" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="document_id" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
```

however neither value when used will give me a actual value other than null. Is this a common occurance?

update: I ended up using the oniteminserting to do a little code behind magic

```
protected void ListView2_OnItemInserting(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sv = ((DropDownList)ListView2.InsertItem.FindControl("DropDownList2iit")).SelectedValue;
    SqlDataSource31.InsertParameters.Add("document_id", sv);

}
```

and it works like it should.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like bellow . ( i am 100% sure but hope fully it's worked)

```
protected void ListView2_OnItemInserting(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sv = ((DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList2iit")).SelectedValue;
    SqlDataSource31.InsertParameters.Add("document_id", sv);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but might help someone.

You are binding your drop down's value to selectedindex property. It should be bound to SelectedValue  instead. No need of writing code for this..

Replace :

```
SelectedIndex='<%# Bind("td_docid") %>'>
```

with

```
SelectedValue= '<%# Bind("td_docid") %>'
```